# Find if set $I$ of all injective functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to find if set $I$ of all injective functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{R}$.
Still, I have no idea how to work with set of functions, it's something new to me since I have only encountered sets of numbers before.

Answer (score 3):

A subset of the injective functions is the set of increasing injective functions. An increasing injective function can be identified with its range, which is just an arbitrary infinite subset of $\Bbb N$. As there are continuum-many subsets of $\Bbb N$ and only countably many of them are finite, we see that there are continuuum-many infnite subsets of $\Bbb N$ and hence *at least* continuum-many injective functions $\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$.

On the other hand, there are *at most* continuum-many injective functions $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ because their graphs are subsets of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, and as $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ is countable and therefore has (only) continuum-many subsets, we are done.