# Is it true that the set $P$ of all injections $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is equal to the set $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\mathbb{R}$-real. $\mathbb{N}$-natural. Is it true that the set $P$ of all injections $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is equal to the set $R$?

Comment: It is suspicious that this exact question was asked 7 minutes ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3636707/find-if-set-i-of-all-injective-functions-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn-i).

Comment: The sets are not equal, only their cardinalities are.